# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'channels')

Tags: javascript, this

I am calling api to return certain json response and I can see successfull response.

```
 MockDataService.getChannelData(function(response){
            if(response){
                this.channels =response;
            }
        });
```

As soon as code hits this.channels = reponse, I get `TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'channels')`

I can't seem to figure out how to ensure scope is correct here. I can't use arrow funtions here due to platform support

Answer (score 0):

Just affixing scope with bind worked

```
MockDataService.getChannelData(function(response) {
    if (response) {
        this.channels = response;
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: James I can't use arrow function due to the devices which are pretty much 15 year old  or more in some cases on which this code will break.

Comment: You did actually mention that in your question!  My bad.